# I want to arrange the list of strings with a certain condition

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I want to arrange the list of strings alphabetically but with the condition that strings that start with x go first. For example, the input is list=['apple','pear','xanadu','stop'].

I'm sure you need to add some condition at the sort function but I'm not sure what to put.

```
list2=[]
string=input("Enter a string:")
list2.append(string)
while string!="stop":
    string=input("Enter a string:")
    list2.append(string)
list2.remove("stop")
print("Your list is:",list2)
print("Sorted list:",sorted(list2))
```

I want the output to be list=['xanadu','apple','pear']. I removed the 'stop' btw.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `key` function that will determine the ordering of elements:

```
>>> sorted(['apple','pear','xanadu','stop'], key=lambda val: (0, val) if val.startswith('x') else (1, val))
['xanadu', 'apple', 'pear', 'stop']
```

The lambda means the following:

```
lambda val:\  # determine the ordering of the element `val`
(0, val)\  # make the algorithm compare tuples!
if val.startswith('x')\
else (1, val)  # use default alphabetical ordering otherwise
```

Since we're now comparing tuples (but ordering the actual values), tuples whose first element is zero will always sort as being greater than those whose first element is 1.